# Tag badge progress not updating automatically

Tags: bug, badge-tracking

I've been tracking my progress toward the silver calculus tag badge. The other day I noticed that the score hadn't changed for a while. Since I answer calculus questions all the time, I knew something was up. I checked the "tags" section of my account page, and saw that indeed my score had increased, but that this fact was not reflected in the progress report. I quickly switched to tracking progress toward a different badge, and then back, and the score updated. But again, it has not updated since. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I've searched meta, but I haven't seen anything like this. I can understand a lag between an event and updating this report, but it seems to me that the lag is pretty long, at least a few days. I am wondering, is this a bug, or is there a reason for this?

**Edit:**

After checking a few other users' profiles, I see that this effects, it seems, everyone.

Comment: Does it help if you temporarily select a different tag badge to track?

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer Do you mean if I track another tag badge, will the progress update for *that* badge, or do you mean have I tried switching to a different tag badge, and then switching back to calculus? If you mean the latter, the answer is sort of. This action seems to trigger a one-time update, with no subsequent auto-updates.

Comment: I meant the latter. Of course the former might also be good to know (confirm that it's not only that one tag).

Comment: At first I thought this might be an issue with CW and your questions in the tag (which are counted as posts, but not towards the badge); but you only asked one question (scored +1) and wrote no CW posts at all. So it's probably a bug indeed.

Comment: @EricWofsey This makes sense, but at this point it hasn't changed in four days.

Comment: I have noticed this as well.  As an additional data point, I also noticed that once I reached 25k reputation (i.e., when I no longer had the option of tracking a privilege instead of a tag badge), my tracked tag badge score began to update every time I visited my profile page. (In fact, the tag score updates every time, even though normally tag scores are only updated once a day.)

Comment: Not to hijack, but where is the calculus badge exactly?  I just looked through the badges I can track for myself and the list of badges on the badges tab but I don't see it.  Do I need more rep before it becomes available?

Comment: @tilper These are tag badges. They are listed as such on the badges page. The bronze badge is awarded for each tag when the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes for your answers on questions with that tag reaches 100, and you have at least 20 answers. The silver is awarded at 400/80 and gold at 1000/200. If you look at the badges earned by some high rep users, you will see several tag badges.

Comment: I see it now.  I was scanning the page for "calculus" which is why I couldn't find it.  Thanks!